# $a = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2})^n$ and $b =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}( 1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $$a = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^n\;\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\;\; b =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\Big( 1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{n^2}$$
>
> then  choose the correct option
>
> - $a= 1, b=\infty$
> - $a=0 ,b=1 $
> - $a=\infty, b=1$
> - $a =1,b=0$

My works : First option  will correct

$a = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2})^n= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}e^\frac{1}{n}=1$

$b =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}( 1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}e^n= \infty$

Is my answer correct or not ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: why down vote @GerryMyerson

Comment: Why are you asking me, Messi? People here downvote for all kinds of reasons, some good, some bad, some incomprehensible.

Comment: I went about it by proving $a=0$ and $b=0$ are absurd then showing $a < \infty$ leaving the first option as the only solution without calculating $b$ at all. It's a strictly worse way to go about it but I get a visceral joy from exploiting poorly posed multiple choice questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalize:

$$
a_{k,l} = \lim (1+\frac{1}{n^k})^{n^l}\\
$$

So $a=a_{2,1}$ and $b=a_{1,2}$

$$
\ln a_{k,l} = \lim n^l \ln (1+\frac{1}{n^k})\\
= \lim \frac{\ln (1+\frac{1}{n^k})}{n^{-l}}\\
= \lim \frac{\frac{-k/n^{k+1}}{(1+\frac{1}{n^k})}}{-l n^{-l-1}}\\
= \lim \frac{k}{l} \frac{n^{l+1}}{n^{k+1} (1+\frac{1}{n^k})}\\
= \lim \frac{k}{l} \frac{n^{l-k}}{(1+\frac{1}{n^k})}\\
$$

If $l>k$ then $\ln a_{k,l} \to + \infty$. If $l<k$, then $\ln a_{k,l} \to 0$ and therefore $a_{k,l} \to 1$.